# iOS Receipt Validation for Paid Apps not for IAP

Tags: ios, swift

I have a situation where i have a paid app (not IAP). i want to know how to validate user that he has properly downloaded the app from App Store in order to detect if there is any fraudulent access to the APP.

Comment: i think your question is s same as this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37566579/ios-test-app-receipt-validation?rq=1
do check it

Comment: as there any think you can offer in order to help?

Comment: Read the link he sent you, it will explain how to check the receipt for the app.